# Exclude 'upload' folder from watch in debug

Tags: nestjs

I am creating an app that use massive upload/download of files. Everything work fine - except in debug mode. Everytime when file change in 'dist/upload' folder (not in 'src'), nest compiler is restarting. Is there an options for exclude some dir/file from --watch. I was trying already creating nodemon.json with exclusion but it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What command are you running in debug mode?

Comment: I run predefined script "start:debug": "nest start --debug=29229 --watch"

Comment: Found a work around: Instead using nest compiler I have configured my project to use webpack as described in docs. Now webpack does not watch in /dist folder and my debug mode work as expected.